# Pandas filtering based on pandas field containing joined string being in list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do data frame filtering using this approach

```
reduced_df = full_df[(full_df['field1'] == some_defined_value1) & \
                     (full_df['field2'] == some_defined_value2) & \
                     (full_df['field3'].apply(lambda x: x for x in ','.join(list_of_comma_separated_string))) & \
                     (full_df['field4'].apply(lambda x: x for x in ','.join(list_of_comma_separated_string)))]
```

I am stuck at the .apply part.   What I am trying to do is to bring in the row if field3 value is in the list of string.  For example:

if a row with

```
field3 = 'apples,oranges,bananas'  # please note it is a single string
```

and I have a

```
list_of_comma_separated_string = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'peaches']
```

then the row should be included in reduced_df.  However if

```
field3 = 'melons,avacado,mint'
```

then the row should not be included in reduced_df.

I tried several approaches (this is my latest attempt) but none seems to work.   This one return error :
generator object is not callable.

Thank you

Comment: Some sample input (more than 1 row) and expected output please

Comment: the full content needs to be in the list of strings?

Comment: @Yuca.  Thanks for catching this.  Any part of the content.

Comment: if you can follow @CodeDifferent suggestion then you'll get an answer pretty quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` and `explode` (pandas 0.25 required) the string, then check if `any` word `isin` the list `l` (no need for the long name).

```
df['field3'].str.split(',').explode().isin(l).any(level=0)
```

#### Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'field1': [1, 1, 2],
                   'field2': [7, 8, 5],
                   'field3': ['apples,oranges,bananas', 'melons,avacado,mint',
                              'crabapples,foo']})
l = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'peaches']

df['field3'].str.split(',').explode().isin(l).any(level=0)
#0     True
#1    False
#2    False
#Name: field3, dtype: bool
```

You would then write your condition like:

```
m = (df['field1'].eq(some_val1) 
     & df['field2'].eq(some_val2) 
     & df['field3'].str.split(',').explode().isin(l).any(level=0)
     & df['field4'].str.split(',').explode().isin(l).any(level=0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Worked like a charm.   I have never seen it done this way and I appreciate it that you shared this approach.